# How to update some data based on array value in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'd like to update some data in Mongoose by using array value that I've find before.

```
Company.findById(id_company,function(err, company) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send({message: "Error, check the console. (Update Company)"});
    }
    const Students = company.students;
    User.find({'_id':{"$in" : Students}},function(err, users) {
        console.log(Students);
        // WANTED QUERY : Update company = null from Users where _id = Students[];
    });
});
```

Students returns users._id in array with object inside, and I use that to find users object, and then I want to set null a field inside users object, that field named as "company". How I can do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you posted (I took the liberty to use `Promises` but you can roughly achieve the same thing with callbacks), you can do something like:

```
    User.find({'_id':{"$in" : Students}})
        .then( users =>{
            return Promise.all( users.map( user => {
                user.company = null;
                return user.save()
            }) );
         })
         .then( () => {
             console.log("yay");
         })
         .catch( e => {
             console.log("failed");
         });
```

Basically, what I'm doing here is making sure `.all()` user models returned by the `.find()` call are saved properly, by checking the Promised value returned for `.save()`ing each of them. 
If one of these fails for some reasons, `Promise.all()` return a rejection you can catch afterhand.

However, in this case, each item will be mapped to a query to your database which is not good. A better strategy would be to use [Model.update()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html), which will achieve the same, in, intrinsically, less database queries.

```
User.update({
    '_id': {"$in": Students}
}, {
    'company': <Whatever you want>
})
.then()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.update` but make sure you pass option `{multi: true}` something like:

```
User.update = function (query, {company: null}, {multi: true}, function(err, result ) { ... });
```